# Flutter force reload image event though the url has not changed

Tags: flutter

Scenario: User goes to the profile page and taps on the profile image (URL a/b/c), which opens the image picker. Then the picked image is uploaded to firebase say a/b/c url. The image has changed now but image URL has not.

I tried using CachedNetworkImage and FadeInImage but both did not refresh the image even when I call setState.

```
setState(() {
   _userProfilePicUrl = _userProfilePicUrl;
 });
```

I also tried following with no luck.

```
await DefaultCacheManager().removeFile(url);
await DefaultCacheManager().putFile(url, bytes);
```

How to refresh the image with the same url without restarting the app.

Comment: URL is key that detects the image from the cache, that's why it not reloading, you need to somehow change the URL from the new image

Comment: the same url is used because given the user name its easy to generate the url without additional lookups.

Comment: without changing the part that matter in the url, you can add a get parameter that changes the cache key (ex : http://example.com/myimage?v=2019... where 2019 is the current datetime)

Comment: yes you can add `System.currentmillis` to your newly created url

Answer (score 3):

After successfully uploading the new file to your server you can call the following static method from CachedNetworkImage class:

```
Future<void> removeUrlFromCache(String photoUrl) async {
    await CachedNetworkImage.evictFromCache(photoUrl);
}
```

It is an asynchronous method so make sure you use the async/await.

By removing the url from the cache, the next time you build a Widget using the CachedNetworkImage Widget and the same photoUrl, the new image will be downloaded and stored in cache:

```
Widget _buildPhotoWidget(String photoUrl) {
    return CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: photoUrl, 
    );
}
```